# unable to push my local git repo to the remote repo

Tags: git, github

when i use the command 
`git push origin master`
The following error is displayed:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': amithld
To https://github.com/amithld/datasciencecoursera.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/amithld/datasciencecoursera.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Even I tried to pull the remote repo, it showed error!
Note: I have already made the remote repo and initialized it with the readme file.

Please, suggest solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the output of `git pull` command. Either you have conflicts or  someone has changed git history.

Comment: $ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the error message closely:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

This means that new commits were made to the remote branch since when you last synched, and now Git does not know how to apply the work you have done since then.  You can resolve this by doing:

```
git pull origin master              # merge the remote into your local branch
```

or

```
git pull --rebase origin master     # rebase your local branch on the remote
```

After this, the following should ideally work:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: woah man...you are awesome.
It worked with the second git pull command.
Just started to work with the git.

Thanks a lot.